# chrome.runtime.connectNative from external url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension which contains the following two files...

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
    "name": "Native Messaging Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Send a message to a native application.",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "index.html"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "nativeMessaging"
    ],
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://*.chrome-extension.com/*"]
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
var sendResponseCallBack;

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        sendResponseCallBack = sendResponse;
        var message = {"comment": '*** ' + request['comment'] + ' ***'};
        var useNative = false;
        if (useNative) {
            connect();
            sendNativeMessage(message);
        }
        else {
            sendResponseCallBack(message);
        }
    }
);
function connect() {
    var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
    port = chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
    port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
}
function sendNativeMessage(message) {
    port.postMessage(message);
}
function onNativeMessage(message) {
    port.disconnect();
    sendResponseCallBack(message);
}
```

I also configured the virtual host: **chrome-extension.com** to access to the url from a local server:

http://www.chrome-extension.com/

With the Chrome extension installed and enabled, if I access to:

http://www.chrome-extension.com/

and the variable `useNative = false` then I get a response from the plugin through: `sendResponseCallBack(message);`, but if `useNative = true` then I don't get any response from the plugin, I get: `undefined` and also the native operation which should take about 5 seconds, doesn't go thru because the `undefined` response is returned in 0 seconds.

I also have enabled another `html` page I access thru the extension url:

**chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/calc-with-os.html**

Inside that page I include the `calc-with-os.js` file which contains the above functions: `connect()` `sendNativeMessage(message)` `onNativeMessage(message)` and the function: `chrome.runtime.connectNative` works properly performing the native process in all its phases.

Any idea on how can I connect to a native process from an external url?

**[EDIT: TRY NUMBER 2]**

Based on the comment of: **@wOxxOm** I did the following modification to the code with the purpose of don't send the message to fast and wait for the native process to start, but it is not still working.

Any other suggestions?

```
var port = null;
var sendResponseCallBack;

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        sendResponseCallBack = sendResponse;
        connect(request);
    }
);
function connect(request) {
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(p){
        port = p;
        port.onMessage.addListener(onNativeMessage);
        port.onDisconnect.addListener(onDisconnected);
        var message = {"comment": '*** ' + request['comment'] + ' ***'};
        sendNativeMessage(message);
    });
    var hostName = "com.google.chrome.example.echo";
    chrome.runtime.connectNative(hostName);
}
function sendNativeMessage(message) {
    port.postMessage(message);
}
function onNativeMessage(message) {
    port.disconnect();
    sendResponseCallBack(message);
}
```

Comment: I guess you're sending the message too soon: the native process needs some time to start. You can make the process send a message on start to your extension. And then you can send messages from extension.

Comment: so, is it possible to connect to a native process from an external url?. I'm gonna check that what you are talking about.

Comment: ups sorry I meant, connect an script on an external url to a native process via a chrome extension

Comment: Yeah, why not. Just solve the timing problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I did `[EDIT: TRY NUMBER 2]` to my question above but with no success. Any other suggestion?

Comment: `sendResponseCallBack` won't work unless you add `return true` at the end of onMessageExternal listener - this will keep the message channel open.